# Yii Error 500: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, yii, file-get-contents, getaddrinfo

yesterday some pages have returned this error:
*Error 500: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known*
I tried to search this problem in relation with Yii framework but I did not found no solutions to this issue.

Comment: Can you show us the code on the error line. I am just guessing that the file url that you provided to `file_get_contents` doesn't exists anymore. (Check that url). If it is on the same server try checking permissions.

Comment: Can you put your code here so, i can review it. ? I think you need to describe more.

Comment: Links are randomly generated with Crypt PHP library using RSA For this reason I cannot know what was the link which generated the error

Comment: then you should use `curl` to check if the url for the file is valid (file exists).

Comment: However, I must to check any generated link before to launch brower request?
So, I don't understand why this problem is occurred now. This web platform is active from 2 months and there have never been any problem of this type.

Comment: You can use the code in my answer to find if the url is active (exists).

Comment: It seems that the error is due to the HTML refresh that I put for refresh page every hour. But what is the relation with the problem?

Comment: I utilise [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking the URLs like this :

```
$ch = curl_init($url); //<=== YOUR URL

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// if $retcode >= 400 -> not found else if $retcode = 200, found.
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: unfortunately, checking the result (200 or 500) gives me the same error even when the result is 200